# Routing with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks, laravel-routing

So I am working on a project and I have decided to use php laravel framework, but when it comes to things like creating a new page and dealing with page redirects etc, am I right in thinking that all these will be handled in the route/web.php file so all the pages for my application will be defined in the route along with the view ?

I was thinking what if my application grows to have dozens of pages is it best practice to define each one on the route or are there better ways to handle this?

Comment: You need to grab a coffee and read some fundamentals https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing and https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers.

Comment: Follow MVC practices; define your Routes, connect it to a Controller, which connects to Model(s) and a View.

Comment: not necessarily, you should handle most of this logic in your page controller. It all depends on the circumstances of the request.

Comment: If your project grows then you can use your own custom route file, may be this will help you to get started https://medium.com/@ntimyeboah/how-to-add-a-custom-route-file-in-laravel-93a087c62424

Comment: @Kyslik haha you are right I should dedicate more time to reading the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best way to do routing is laravel to have each route for . each page, the only exception is when you have dynamic routes, for example, if you have a route that checks for users id or category for some product etc and it looks something like this Route::get("/product/{$category_id}","FrontController@methodForGetingProduct").
And later in Controller, you define what will you send and receive of the information and what view should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this type routing .......

[image]

Comment: Would it not be better prw rice to create custom route Giles for get/post requests etc ?